# How can i create a polygonal responsive div?

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive

i've been trying to create a layout with a non-rectangular div, its a pentagon to be more precise,

I've tried using svg but the image doesn't appear when using firefox, also, one other requirement is for the div to scale well into smaller screens (responsive), but again, i tried using percentages as the points of the pentagon but that certainly didn't take me nowhere (also, on the text i used percents as the x and y but it also fails to rescale in smaller screens),

here is what I've got so far:

```css
polygon {
  fill: url(#image);
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-shape">
  <svg width="1440px" viewBox="0 0 1440 940" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet">
          <defs>
            <pattern id='image' height='940' width='1440' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'>
              <image xlink:href='https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/12/87/pzB7wF.jpg' height='940' width='1440' />
            </pattern>
          </defs>
          <g>
            <polygon points='0,0 1440,0 1440,727 503,940 0,719' />
            <text x="20%" y="5%0"  font-size="90px" fill="blue" > New MODEL! </text>
          </g>
        </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe this post help you https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/creating-responsive-shapes-with-clip-path/

Comment: Your CSS file does not contain an element with the ID image, that's in the HTML file so you can't write a local reference to it in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i created a div with the height and width that the polygon would have had it been a square, and used inline svg clipPaths with relative units for firefox and a clipPath defined on the css for webkit browsers, couldn´t really make it work on iexplorer, here is my code

Since i needed to add content inside the div itself, and also put an overlay on the background, this proved to be the best course of action

```css
#index-banner {
  position: relative;
  height: 65.29vw;
  /*to keep aspect ratio*/
  width: 100vw;
  /*to adjust the banner to the browser window*/
  background-image: url(https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/12/87/pzB7wF.jpg);
  background-color: #615966;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 77.3%, 34.9% 100%, 0% 76%);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip-index" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <polygon points='0,0 1,0 1,0.773 0.349,1 0,0.76 0,0' />
            </clipPath>           
        </defs>
    </svg>

<div class="section no-pad-bot valign-wrapper hide-on-med-and-down" id="index-banner" style="clip-path: url('#clip-index');">
  <div class="content of the polygonal div"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `width` and `height` attributes from the `<svg>` element.
2. Add the SVG to you page, either directly into html, as `<img>` or via css background image.
3. Setup the css that way, so that the svg gets scaled up to the width of the container (parent), what depends on the the way you added the svg. (f.i. `background-size: 100%` if it is a background image or `width: 100%` if it is an element)

This should do the trick.